# $(window).scroll(function() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With strange reasons $(window).scroll() not working. I am working on this for a while but I can't figured out what silly thing I am doing in it.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/KHeZY/38/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // fill body with data so we can see the scroll
    for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {        
        $('#list').append(i+'<br>');
    }
    // jQuery plug-in
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == 800)
        {
            alert('mission accomplished');
        }
    });
});
```

Console error

```
TypeError: window.scrollTop is not a function
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: It works just fine. You're probably not getting the expected result, because you will never hit exactly 800. Try using >= 800 - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHeZY/40/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/KHeZY/39/

It is not always necessary that `$(window).scroll()` stops at 800, this event only triggers after you stop scrolling `$(window).scrollTop()`

you need to set some window for it.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 800 && $(window).scrollTop() < 850)
    {
        alert('mission accomplished');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working :( I can clearly see my log on the $(document).ready() function. But my $(window).scroll(function() { console.log("test"); }); function doesn't work, regardless if I put it inside the ready or outside. Any advice ?